# supertabular and twocolumn blank column

Tags: two-column, supertabular

We are using minipage supertabular with a twocolumn mode for our reports and were observing strange behaviour lately.

There are some cases, when the subsubsection is at the top of the second column and the supertabular elements don't fit below it, though there is place for them, therefore they get skipped to the next page. This produces an ugly blank column with the section at the top.

Here is an example, which reproduces this behaviour:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{counter}
\forloop{counter}{1}{\value{counter} < 44}{
  placeholder\\
}

\mbox{}\newline
\subsubsection*{Research in Astrophysics}
\begin{mpsupertabular}{p{1,4cm} p{6,1cm}}
E1.1 & Accreting Neutron Stars\\ & MSO: Name of a scientist \\
\end{mpsupertabular}\\


\end{document}
```

There are several ways to fix it manually (insert `\newpage` before subsubsection, wrap the subsubsection and the next supertabular with `\vbox{}`).

But the question is how to prevent it from happening for an automated output?

For some reason ST thinks there is no page height left for the table (found through `\sttraceon`), so it inserts a pagebreak. Is it a bug?